# Integration user can't be used for Lead conversion

Tags: apex, integration, permissions, permission-sets, lead-conversion

I'm trying to get the Integration user to convert a Lead via REST API. But it seems Integration License cannot have App permissions like Lead conversion.

I created a Permission set with Convert Lead access, but when I'm assigning it it says 'Failure : Can't assign permission set Integration Permission set to user SF Integration User. The user license doesn't allow App Permissions.

I tried cloning the Integration profil, no luck.

Tried ticking 'Sales Anywhere' checkbox user, It asked me to contact salesforce to get additional license for it, wonder if this is an additional paid license? and also could it work on top of API Integration license? don't want to go down this path and then find it still cannot be assigned. Any thoughts on this?

Is there a way to achieve this without having to use a Salesforce full license?

Thanks!

Comment: `Based on your use case, your integration user may also need additional permission set licenses, in addition to the Salesforce API Integration permission set license. If you run into an issue where you are unable to assign a specific permission set license, open a case with Salesforce Support indicating that you are unable to assign the specific permission set license to a user with the Salesforce Integration user license.` see [article](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2023/best-practices-for-configuring-your-integration-user). Did you assign the PS `Salesforce API integration` to user?

Comment: Thanks @cropredy Yes, I did. updated the question to make it clear. I wonder if you can assign multiple permission sets with different licenses on top of integration license opening up it's capabilities? cheers!

Comment: did you create the PS without any specific license associated to it (leave dropdown box blank)?

Comment: @cropredy I could create a permission set with Sales console license which is the only license appearing to select. But Again it can't be added to Integration user as it throws same error Integration User can't be assigned the Sales Console User permission set license, because Integration User's user license doesn't support it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the steps

- Create the User `Test Integration User`.

  - Assign User License `Salesforce Integration`
  - Assign Profile `Salesforce API-only System Integrations`
- For that user, go to the `Permission Set License Assignment` related list and assign `Salesforce API Integration`. Note this is a Permission Set **License** Assignment, not a Permission Set Assignment. The UX for this clearly states that `Salesforce API Integration` has access to `Convert Leads`

[image]

- Create a new Permission Set called `Lead Convert`

  - Leave the field for `License` (a dropdown) blank
  - Check the box for the `Lead Convert` permission in `App Permissions`. This also grants CRUD on Lead/Account/Contact/Opportunity.
- Assign this new `Lead Convert` Permission Set to the user `Test Integration User`

The permission is now assigned to the integration user. I used the [PermComparator](https://perm-comparator.herokuapp.com/) tool to verify

[image]

The screen shot that proves that Convert Leads is available in the Salesforce API Integration Permission Set License is shown below

[image]

Comment: Thanks @cropredy!