# Salesforce integration user subscription

Tags: api, integration

I am currently developing integration with Salesforce which would sync data (apply Create, Update, Delete, Get operations on entity items) on Salesforce side. As licenses are not cheap and i would like to use dedicated (integration) user for that integration.

I tried cloning profile Salesforce API Only System Integrations and newly created clone assigned to my user. But i could not access basic endpoints like `sObject/describe`. I suspect thats because i got it wrong and im not supposed to clone that profile.

So my question is what is qualified as integration user to not require normal user licence but integration user licences (5 FREEs and next for 10$). Is limiting API only access enough to qualify as integration user ?

Comment: May I know, do you include the Permission set license `Salesforce API Integration` to your new user which having the cloned API integration profile? Because by default that profile doesn't having any object access. All the object permissions are provided via that above Permission set license / Custom Permission sets only.

Comment: Thank you for response. I didn t had it. Just now i activated it, sign in again via connected app but still same response: NOT_FOUND (when i had standard user profile same request returned content). Is this license set only to be able to count it to integration subscription and then i can clone standard user for profile setting ?

Comment: Can you please help to update your question by adding the error snapshot to understood this issue bit more? which will help the community users as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integration user can't be used for Lead conversion](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/412390/integration-user-cant-be-used-for-lead-conversion)

Answer (score 0):

This is not well-documented.  First, be sure you have assigned the [Salesforce API Integration permission set license](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2023/best-practices-for-configuring-your-integration-user).  But by default this does not grant CRUD access to any standard or custom objects.  You must build a custom permission set and enter all the desired objects' permissions for this integration user.

Comment: N.B. - a step-by-step example is [shown here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/412398/2602)

Comment: so difference between paying full price for user or discounted for integration user is by selecting right permission set license ? (I never was on standard salesforce, only developers edition, so i can t tell)